# Distinct numbering in document and ToC in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, memoir

I am using a section numbering scheme based on legislative numbering, that looks like this:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{%
§\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{%
(\arabic{subsection})}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{%
({\itshape\alph{subsubsection}})}
```

I would like my section headings to be numbered `\thesection\thesubsection\thesubsubsection`, etc.

[image]

However, in the ToC, I would like the subsection to be numbered only by `\thesubection` etc.
[image]

In the Book class, I can use `titlesec` and `tocloft` to accomplish this (which is how I made examples in the screenshots above), but is it possible in memoir? I can't see how to do it with `\setsecnumformat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example on page 99.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand\thesection{% how you want it to appear in the TOC
§\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{%
(\arabic{subsection})}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{%
({\itshape\alph{subsubsection}})}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\setsecnumformat{\csname #1secnumformat\endcsname}
\newcommand\sectionsecnumformat{\thesection\quad}
\newcommand\subsectionsecnumformat{\thesection\thesubsection\quad}
\newcommand\subsubsectionsecnumformat{\thesection\thesubsection\thesubsubsection\quad}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section Title}

\subsection{Subsection Title}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic; thank you so much!